# didSelectRowAt indexPath play Audio

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, audio-player

I need your help! I am developing and Audio Player application with the Jukebox API. I am using didSelectRowAt indexPath to play the current stream. My code works but it does not stop the stream before playing another one with a cell is clicked. I would be grateful for any help! Thanks!

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self as? JukeboxDelegate, items: [
            JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string:audio_url[indexPath.row])! as URL)
            ])

      jukebox.play()

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            stopJukeBox()
            jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self as? JukeboxDelegate, items: [
                JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string:audio_url[indexPath.row])! as URL)
                ])
            playJukeBox()

}

func stopJukeBox(){
  if jukebox != nil {
   jukebox.stop()
  }
}

func playJukeBox(){
  if jukebox != nil {
    jukebox.play()
   }
}
```

or you can directly handle play and stop in didSelect function

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

   // Stop
   if jukebox != nil {
    jukebox.stop()
   }


            jukebox = Jukebox(delegate: self as? JukeboxDelegate, items: [
                JukeboxItem(URL: NSURL(string:audio_url[indexPath.row])! as URL)
                ])

   // play
   if jukebox != nil {
    jukebox.play()
   }

}
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thanks so much!